# C++/GCC: How to detect unhandled exceptions in compile time

Tags: c++, gcc, exception

**Introduction:**
In Java, if you do not catch an exception, your code doesn't even compile, and the compiler crashes on unhandled exception.

**Question:**
Is there a way to tell GCC to be "strict" as Java in this case, and to raise an error or at least a warning on unhandled exception?

If not - are there IDEs (for Unix, please) that can highlight such cases as a warning?

Comment: Since any function can throw an exception without a formal specification, it's impossible. And remember that "crashes" (like segmentation faults) aren't exceptions that can be caught with a C++ `catch` statement, and they too can happen anywhere.

Comment: I agree about the segmentation faults. I just want to avoid the sudden crashes on exceptions that were thrown and not handled. I want to know about all of the calls that can raise exceptions, and to handle them

Comment: The default behaviour for unhandled exceptions is to call `std::terminate`. A custom handler can be installed with [`std::set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate). It may not solve your immediate problem, but it gives your application one last "look" at the unhanded exception.

Comment: I'm not that GCC or Unix expert. Maybe it's possible to register some kind of exception handlers per process/thread like on windows (SEH, VEH). On windows you can catch every kind of exception with these handlers. If something like this exists on unix this could be your way. But I didn't know what would be the terms to search on.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in C++. Exception specification is a part of a function *declaration* but not a part of its *type*. Any indirect call (via pointer or virtual call) just completely wipes any information about exceptions.

Exception specifications are deprecated anyway in C++11 in favour of `noexcept`, so it is unlikely any compiler would bother to enhance this language feature.

Comment: Which feature is depracated in C++11?

Comment: [Exception specifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) in favor of `noexcept`, @user3322273.

Answer (score 0):

The only guarantee you can put on a C++ function is that it never throws an exception at all:

```
void f() noexcept;
```

However, this will terminate the program at runtime when an exception is thrown. It's not verified at compile-time.

If you want to guarantee that an error is handled, the closest you can get is returning a value of a type that wraps `boost::variant<OK, Error>` with a member function that takes two callbacks: a callback for the `OK` case and one for the `Error` case.

Comment: I want to throw exceptions and to handle them, as it enables informative debug messages, so the `noexcept` is not an option for me. The {ok, error} struct is a solution I commonly use in `Perl`, but I thought in C++ I would be able to use efficiently the exceptions mechanism.. I may use this solution if I have no choise

Answer (score 0):

You can ALWAYS use:

```
int main()
{
   try {
      ... your usual main ... 
   }
   catch(...)
   {
       std::cerr << "Unhandled exception caught" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

However, that is a fairly poor solution.

Unfortunately, the nature of C++ makes it very hard to catch the situation where something throws an exception and it's not handled, since just about everything has the potential to throw exceptions. I can only think of code-review - perhaps code analyzing tools, such as that built around [CLANG](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/index.html) will have the capability of doing this, but it probably won't be 100% accurate. In fact, I'm not even sure that the Clang Analyzer fully understands throw/try/catch currently, as it seems to not catch some fairly fundamental errors http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/potential_checkers.html (see the "exceptions" heading).

Answer (score 0):

First, your statement concerning Java is false; only certain
types of exceptions prevent the code from compiling.  And for
the most part, those types of exceptions correspond to things
that are better handled by return codes.  Exceptions are normally
only an appropriate solution when propagating an error through
a large number of functions, and you don't want to have to add
exception specifications for all of those functions.

That's really why Java makes its distinctions: exceptions that
derive from `java.lang.Error` should usually be crashes
(assertion failures and the like in C++); and exceptions that
derive from `java.lang.RuntimeException` should be exceptions in
C++.  Neither are checked in Java, either, because it isn't
reasonable to have every function declare that it might throw
one of them.

As for the rest, the exceptions which you want to catch
immediately in the calling code, they are generally best handled
by return codes, rather than exceptions; Java may use exceptions
here because it has no out arguments, which can make using
return codes more awkward.  Of course, in C++, you can also
silently ignore return codes, which is a drawback (but
historical reasons, etc.).  But the real issue is the contract,
which is far more complex than function f might throw/return x;
it's more along the lines of "function f *will* throw/return x,
if condition c is met".  And I know of no language which has
a means of enforcing that.  In C++ (and for checked exceptions
in Java), exception specifications are more along the lines of
"function f will not throw anything but x".  Which is generally
not very useful, unless "x" means *all* exceptions.  In order to
write really robust code, you need a few functions which are
guaranteed never to throw.  Interestingly enough, you *can*
specify this in C++, both pre-C++11 (`throw()`) and post
(`noexcept`); you cannot in Java, because you can't specify that
a function won't throw a `java.lang.RuntimeError`.

(Or a `java.lang.Error`, but that's less of an issue, since if
you get one of those, you're application is hosed anyway.  Just
how are you expected to recover from
`java.lang.VirtualMachineError`?  And of course, you can't
really expect to be able to recover from a segment violation in
C++ either.  Although...  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` derives
from `java.lang.VirtualMachineError`; although not easy, and not
always applicable, I've written C++ code which successfully
recovered from `std::bad_alloc`.)